How to run a script every time youtube.com/watch page is viewed?
I'm writing a Chrome extension that should run upon visiting a Youtube watch page youtube.com/watch?. I've read this question from 10 years ago and the solutions there seem to work inconsistently.
My manifest.json has this. I believe this means that content.js should run on every Youtube page instead of just watch pages.
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"]
    }
]

My content.js file currently has an event listener, which I got from this article. I find that this does not run every time a watch page is loaded. I sometimes need to refresh the watch page for the script to run.
Functionally, I am reading the current time, duration, and playback speed of the video to calculate the remaining view time, then display this time in the video info panel.
document.addEventListener("yt-navigate-start", removeRemainingTime);
document.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", setupRemainingTimeDisplay);

let intervalId;

function setupRemainingTimeDisplay() {
  const video = document.querySelector("video");
  const timeWrapper = document.querySelector(".ytp-time-wrapper");

  if (timeWrapper && video) {
    // Create or find the existing span for remaining time
    let remainingTime = document.querySelector(".remaining-time");
    if (!remainingTime) {
      remainingTime = document.createElement("span");
      remainingTime.className = "remaining-time";
      remainingTime.style.color = "#ddd";
      timeWrapper.appendChild(remainingTime);
    }

    // Update remaining time every second
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      updateRemainingTime(video, remainingTime);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function updateRemainingTime(video, remainingTime) {
  const { duration, playbackRate, currentTime } = video;

  if (!duration || isNaN(playbackRate) || isNaN(currentTime)) {
    remainingTime.textContent = " • Invalid time";
    return;
  }

  const timeLeft = calculateRemainingTime(currentTime, playbackRate, duration);
  remainingTime.textContent = ` • ${formatTimestamp(timeLeft)} left`;
}

function calculateRemainingTime(currentTime, playbackRate, duration) {
  return Math.max((duration - currentTime) / playbackRate, 0);
}

function formatTimestamp(seconds) {
  const totalSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
  const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
  const minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
  const secs = totalSeconds % 60;

  if (hours > 0) {
    return `${hours}:${String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")}:${String(
      secs
    ).padStart(2, "0")}`;
  } else {
    return `${minutes}:${String(secs).padStart(2, "0")}`;
  }
}

function removeRemainingTime() {
  const remainingTimeElements = document.querySelectorAll(".remaining-time");
  remainingTimeElements.forEach((element) => element.remove());
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

How can I make sure that content.js runs each time a youtube watch page is visited?

Since you're building an extension, you should add the code of the content.js and please explain what do you want to do with this extension.

@MauricioAriasOlave Apologies, just included my content.js logic

There are several possible solutions for this issue.
One option is to use history.pushState, but YouTube doesn’t trigger this event by default. An alternative approach would be to use MutationObserver to detect when the page content has changed.
Combining both methods could potentially yield better results.
The optimal approach depends on the logic within your content.js file.
Here’s a sample code demonstrating how to use MutationObserver:
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      const video = document.querySelector('video');
      if (video) {
        removeRemainingTime();
        setupRemainingTimeDisplay();
      }
    }
  });
});

